# "Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions" on Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

After several hours spent on this forum trying to test a lot of solutions, I need your help.
For the first time, I faced the following message on Firebase Crashlytics which does not allow me to see crashes reports : "Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions".

I tried to follow the steps explained on the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0) finding the dSym files on my computer (it seems it's not possible to download them from AppleStore Connect) on two different locations :

- /Users/sebastien/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-11-15/MyApp\ 15-11-2020\ 21.26.xcarchive/dSYMs
- /Users/sebastien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dqcgovtkqjsbjdciehfjshknjraj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator

I uploaded them and, despite of the successful message "Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols", **it does not change anything on Firebase**.

Some useful information:

- I'm using the following run script for Crashlytics : "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"  (without any input files so far but it did not cause any trouble so I assume it does not come from this), as explained in the [Firebase Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=ios)
- The "Debug Information format" setting is indeed set to "DWARF with dSYM file" for all targets
- I'm using Pods in my project

What can I do more to finally have the crash reports available on Firebase as for all my previous versions ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you should add this script to following run script:
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
and no need to add this : ${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run

Comment: No need to add this : ${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run? But this is exactly what Firebase mention in this tutorial, why this could be possibly the cause of my problem?

Comment: as Fabric is replaced with FirebaseCrashlytics, in order to achieve this automatic mechanism, you can create a new run script and paste this script there:
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"

Comment: This script will get the dSYM files and upload them to firebase servers so that you can see the crashes.